# AutoTimeStamp based on multiple cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a document that when any cell from column B through G has data entered into it (starting from row 4) I want Row A to have a TimeStamp of when that data was started and to not change. But if the row is cleared I want the timestamp to be deleted and be able to be reentered with new data. And I'm using this across multiple sheets. I did the IFS function and it worked, but people were overwriting and deleting it so I am trying to script it. I've tried modifying a few scripts I've found online and using some of the stuff I remember from college days, but it hasn't been great and I could use some help. Thanks!

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
  var range = ss.getRangeList(['B4:B', 'C4:C','D4:D','E4:E', 'F4:F', 'G4:G']);
  if ( e.range) return;
  e.targetColumn = 1
  .setValue (new Date("HH:mm"));
}

function onEdit(e) {
  if ( e.range.columnStart !== 2 && e.range.columnStart !== 3 
    && e.range.columnStart !== 4 && e.range.columnStart !== 5 
    && e.range.columnStart !== 6 && e.range.columnStart !== 7) return;
e.range.targetColumn = 1
    .setValue(new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Updated) Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && e.range.columnStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart < 8 && e.range.rowStart > 3) {
    e.source.toast('Flag1');
    if(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,2,1,sh.getLastColumn() -1).isBlank() ) {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart(),1).clearContent();
    } else {
      if(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).isBlank()) {
        sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).setValue(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I put in my sheet name and I tried it out and got the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined". I tried to just use it and it wouldn't timestamp.

Comment: try modify the code, from `setValues(new Date());` to `setValue(new Date());`

Comment: I just approved the edit that Mr. Shane created.

Comment: Thanks so much!!

Comment: The only issue is that when any of the cells from column B-G are edited the time updates. Is there a way to make the time static to the first entry?

Comment: Try the modification

Comment: Thanks @Cooper I'm not sure why it wasn't working before, but it is now. Although now it's not deleting the timestamp when the rest are empty and I tried reloading the page. Am I messing up somewhere? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Please add the e.source.toast() that I added and also check the executions when the timestamp should be being deleted to see if there are errors.